# Render a partial only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Is there any way to render a partial only once. What I am trying to say here is I have a partial

_popup_message.html.erb. I am rendering this partial from multiple places on a same page. The problem is inside the partial I have few id attributes. So, if the partial is getting rendered multiple times on a page so HTML is giving error that id attribute is used twice or thrice.
 So, is there any way in rails by which I can check whether that partial already rendered if yes then don't render it.

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-centered columns"> 
    <div class="popup-message">  
        <%= dashboard_tile_message.html_safe %>  
          ###so if the below partial got rendered once I don't want to render it 
          <%= render :partial => 'popup_message', locals: { user: current_user, setting: settings } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you render the same partial multiple times? Why can't you just render it once?

Comment: @spickermann Actually  I have a page it has multiple sections. In each section, I am rendering the partial on some condition. What my partial is doing rendering an image with promo message ANd when the user clicks on it I am opening a popup

Comment: I doubt rails has a built-in way to do this but you can achieve it with an instance variable and a conditional (`unless @modal_rendeded`).

Comment: @max  Actually I am trying to achieve it with instance variable but it is not working for me. Can you give an example

Comment: Then show that attempt. I think you can pull this off on your own. Its not exactly rocket science.

Comment: @max I got the solution but it worked with the help of class variable instead of instance variables. Please see I have posted my solution if you have any better approach let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: allowing a partial to only be rendered once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690727/rails-allowing-a-partial-to-only-be-rendered-once)

Comment: @motoxer4533 It didn't worked for me I tried some other approach

Answer (score 1):

If someone got struggled, here the example what @max  want to propose(haml):

````
- @rendered ||= false
- unless @rendered 
  #- Your partial code
- @rendered = true```
````